# Display div when radio button selected - combining javascripts

Tags: javascript, radio-button

I am trying to display the contents of a div based on the radio button option selected in a radio button group. The tricky part is that there is another radio button group one level up whose choice needs to control the second radio button group's choice. For example:

Radio Button Group 1
Options: A, B, C

Radio Button Group 2
Options: X, Y, Z

When "A" is selected, I need "X" to be auto-selected. When X is selected in this way, Div-01 needs to be displayed.

When "B" is selected, I need "Y" to be auto-selected. When Y is selected in this way, Div-02 needs to be displayed.

etc...

I've been cobbling together different javascript snippets and have been able to get either the auto-selection OR the "display div" functionality to work, but never both at the same time. Here are the various snippets I have been using. I'm hoping someone here can shed some light on how to modify/combine these so all of the functions will work....

AUTO-SELECTION:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("input[name='radiogroup1']").change(function(){
if($("input[name='radiogroup1']:checked").val() == "A")
{
   $("input:radio[name='radiogroup2'][value='X']").attr('checked', 'checked');
}
if($("input[name='radiogroup1']:checked").val() == "B")
{
   $("input:radio[name='radiogroup2'][value='Y']").attr('checked', 'checked');
}
if($("input[name='radiogroup1']:checked").val() == "C")
{
   $("input:radio[name='radiogroup2'][value='Z']").attr('checked', 'checked');
}
});
});</script>
```

DIV DISPLAY:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#showfield1').click(function () {
    $('#div2').hide('fast');
    $('#div3').hide('fast');
    $('#div1').show('fast');
});
$('#showfield2').click(function () {
    $('#div1').hide('fast');
    $('#div3').hide('fast');
    $('#div2').show('fast');
});
$('#showfield3').click(function () {
    $('#div1').hide('fast');
    $('#div2').hide('fast');
    $('#div3').show('fast');
});
});
</script>
```

CSS for the DIV DISPLAY:

```
.testfields div{
    display: none;
}
```

HTML for the DIV DISPLAY:

```
<div class="testfields" align="center" style="padding:25px;width: 300px;">
                   <div id="div1">Text for Div 1</div>
                   <div id="div2">Text for Div 2</div>
                   <div id="div3">Text for Div 3</div>
              </div>
```

FORM 1

```
<form name="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="radio" value="A" name="radiogroup1" /> A<br />
  <input type="radio" value="B" name="radiogroup1" /> B<br />
  <input type="radio" value="C" name="radiogroup1" /> C<br />
</form>
```

FORM 2

```
<form name="form2" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="radio" value="X" name="radiogroup2" id="showfield1" /> X<br />
  <input type="radio" value="Y" name="radiogroup2" id="showfield2" /> Y<br />
  <input type="radio" value="Z" name="radiogroup2" id="showfield3" /> Z<br />
</form>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You may change your each if conditions as below :`if($("input[name='radiogroup1']:checked").val() == "A")
{
   $("input:radio[name='radiogroup2'][value='X']").attr('checked', 'checked'); $('#div2').hide('fast');
    $('#div3').hide('fast');
    $('#div1').show('fast');
}`

Comment: @PankajKathiriya, Thanks for your reply! I created a JSFiddle with your code, but it is not working. Can you please check it and let me know if I am doing something wrong?  http://jsfiddle.net/xCfv6/

Answer (score 0):

You should use prop instead of attr. Your current code fires the change event just once, i.e. the second time you choose radio buttons, the radiogroup2 does not get updated. The following code snippet does what you are looking for.

```
            $("input[name='radiogroup1']").change(function () {
                switch ($("input[name='radiogroup1']:checked").val()) {
                    case "A":
                        checkRadio(0); showField(0);
                        break;
                    case "B":
                        checkRadio(1); showField(1);
                        break;
                    case "C":
                        checkRadio(2); showField(2);
                        break;
                }

            });
            var checkRadio= function(idx) {
                $("input:radio[name='radiogroup2']").each(function(i){
                    if (i == idx)
                        $(this).prop('checked', 'checked');
                    else
                        $(this).prop('checked', false);
                });

            }
            var showField = function (idx) {
                $('.testfields div').each(function (i) {
                    if (i == idx)
                        $(this).show('fast');
                    else
                        $(this).hide('fast');
                });
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I created a JSFiddle with your code, but it doesn't seem to be working at all. Can you please check it and see if I did something wrong?    http://jsfiddle.net/A3teY/

Comment: you forgot to choose jquery and onDomReady on the left. It works as intended. I updated the fiddle.